# Set flag to check if parameters are filled in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to have a flag that checks if parameters are filled:

```
var var1 = "hello"
var var2 = "hi there"
var flag1 = (var1 && var2)

console.log('flag1 = ' + flag1)
```

However, running this code prints

```
flag1 = hi there
```

How can I code it in such a way that it will be set to `true` if both `var1` and `var2` are not empty? I do not want to use `isEmpty()` since actual code will be checking quite a number of parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: Parameters? Is this in a function? Can you post the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boolean

```js
var var1 = "hello"
var var2 = "hi there"
var flag1 = Boolean(var1 && var2)

console.log('flag1 = ' + flag1)
```

P.S:- With the given example i consider your inputs will always be strings

Answer (score 0):

You could use double negations,

```
var flag1 = (!!var1 && !!var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got stuck with implicit type casting I guess.

You could do:

```
var flag1 = (typeof var1 != null && typeof var2 != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

**var flag1 = typeof(var1) !== 'undefined' && typeof(var2) !== 'undefined';**

Using typeof for the check will deal with all non-truthy values and when the variable itself was never declared.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var var1 = "hello";
var var2 = "hi there";
var flag1 = (var1 && var2) ? true : false
console.log("flag1 is " + flag1);
```